# Apply a polymorphic function to two different types of inputs

Tags: haskell, types, parametric-polymorphism

Consider this function:

```
doToBoth f x y = (f x, f y)
```

It works as expected in simple cases:

```
doToBoth (2 *) 10 15 == (20, 30)
doToBoth head [1,2] [3,4,5] == (1, 3)
```

Then I tried these ones:

```
doToBoth head [1,10,100] "apple"
doToBoth pred 2 'b'
```

I want those to both result in `(1, 'a')`, but instead they just result in a type error. The problem is that the inferred type of `doToBoth` isn't polymorphic enough:

```
doToBoth :: (a1 -> a2) -> a1 -> a1 -> (a2, a2)
```

Seeing this, I tried adding an explicit type signature to fix it:

```
doToBoth :: (t ~ (i1 -> o1), t ~ (i2 -> o2)) => t -> i1 -> i2 -> (o1, o2)
```

This type signature was accepted, but it didn't fix the problem, and checking what happened with `:t doToBoth` revealed that it ended up with a type equivalent to the original inferred one:

```
doToBoth :: (i2 -> o2) -> i2 -> i2 -> (o2, o2)
```

What is the correct way to write a type signature to make this function work the way I want?

Comment: ^ You can let me know if that doesn't fully answer your question. It should be a somewhat smallish modification to get something that fulfills your specific question here, but I could give more details on that modification if you'd like.

Comment: @DavidYoung Your answer there looks almost perfect. It was fairly straightforward to convert it to use visible type applications instead of proxies and to add a new class/instance to support the `head` function (I can edit either or both of those into your answer there if you want). The only wart about it is that it doesn't really work on the `length` function, but rather on the function `length . toList`. I tried for a little while to fix that with the various new GHC extensions since you wrote that back in 2015, but with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

Accepting a polymorphic argument makes your function rank-2 polymorphic. GHC has [an extension for that](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-RankNTypes), but you can only use it if you can somehow quantify over what kinds of types the argument must support – with type constructors or -classes. For instance, for the case of lists you could write

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types, UnicodeSyntax #-}
doToBoth_listelem :: (∀ x . [x] -> x) -> [a] -> [b] -> (a,b)
doToBoth_listelem f x y = (f x, f y)
```

```
> doToBoth_listelem head [1,10,100] "apple"
(1,'a')
```

This would also work for the `pred` example, and is somewhat more useful. In this case you need to quantify over an argument that's constrained by the `Enum` class:

```
doToBoth_enum :: (Enum a, Enum b)
      => (∀ x . Enum x => x -> x) -> a -> b -> (a,b)
doToBoth_enum f x y = (f x, f y)
```

```
> doToBoth_enum pred 2 'b'
(1,'a')
```

Writing it so it automatically works for any such constraint that the argument might require is, I think, not possible. It might be possible to approximate that with some clever type families and constraint kinds, but I doubt it would end up being practically usable.

Comment: With the solution you describe, it seems like for every different type of `f`, I'd need a different version of `doToBoth` for it, which isn't very convenient. What I really want is what you say is impossible or at least impractical in your last paragraph. I'll leave this open for a few days in case anyone else can think of a way to do it, or for an answer that explains what's missing from Haskell's type system that makes it impossible.

Comment: @JosephSible I can't find a general way to do that, unless I exploit intersection types, which are *not* available in Haskell (IIRC, inference is undecidable with intersection types, and type checking is too expensive). I think you need something like `doBoth :: ((a->a') && (b->b')) -> a -> b -> (a', b')`, which Haskell does not have.

Comment: I wanted to write `forall c. (c a, c b) => (forall x. c x => x -> x) -> a -> b -> (a, b)`, but that didn’t work. I found sort of a way to do it with `ConstraintKinds` if you pass the dictionaries explicitly, but it’s not worth the trouble: given `both :: forall a b c. Dict (c a) -> Dict (c b) -> (forall x. Dict (c x) -> x -> x) -> a -> b -> (a, b)` you invoke it as `both (Dict :: Dict (Enum Int)) (Dict :: Dict (Enum Char)) (\ Dict -> pred) 2 'b'`. Might be a starting point for something more clever though.

Comment: @JonPurdy That looks like it would only work when `f` is an endomorphism, which `head` isn't.

Comment: @JosephSible: Right, was just going off the second example in this answer (`doToBoth_enum`)